# Angular cannot find module 'net'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

When I added a dependency in simple Angular CLI app

```
import {Socket} from 'net';
```

I get error when run 'ng start'

```
ERROR in C:/IdeaProjects/GethIPC/src/app/app.component.ts (5,20): Cannot find module 'net'
```

Comment: isn't it a nodejs module? I think you cannot use it in angular

Comment: This nodejs module

Comment: just build a `nodejs server` with `Socketio` and talk to that server with your angular app https://medium.com/@REPTILEHAUS/angular-2-and-socket-io-chat-app-f56afb9ceeb2  https://github.com/jussikinnula/angular-socket-io-chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to import a node module - `net`, but it is not available in the browser. You'll need a socket for your client, e.g. [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) but that of course depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I want to use ipc connection with application geth from angular.     

      var net = require('net');
var web3 = new Web3('/Users/myuser/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc', net);
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.IpcProvider('/Users/myuser/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc', net));